# Why does my flutter app take so long on iOS to load?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I added fcm push notifications to my flutter app and now it takes so long on iOS. It just shows a white screen for like 10 minutes and then finally loads. How can i stop it from taking so long? The first time it works fine. After you kill the app and bring it back it breaks. Here is a video:

[Video Link](https://streamable.com/tahksx)

Here is my part of my main.dart:

```
// TODO: Add stream controller
final _messageStreamController = BehaviorSubject<RemoteMessage>();

// TODO: Define the background message handler
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // TODO: Request permission
  final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Permission granted: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }
  // TODO: Register with FCM

  const vapidKey = "KEY_NUMBERS";

  // use the registration token to send messages to users from your trusted server environment
  String? token;

  if (DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform == DefaultFirebaseOptions.web) {
    token = await messaging.getToken(
      vapidKey: vapidKey,
    );
  } else {
    token = await messaging.getToken();
  }

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Registration Token=$token');
  }
  // TODO: Set up foreground message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Handling a foreground message: ${message.messageId}');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }

    _messageStreamController.sink.add(message);
  });

  final SetPushNotifTokenService _setPushNotifTokenService = SetPushNotifTokenService();
  SetPushNotifToken? _setPushNotifToken;
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String? action = prefs.getString('session');
  if(action != null && token != null) {
    SetPushNotifToken setPushNotifToken = await _setPushNotifTokenService
        .setPushNotifToken(action, token);
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // set value
    await prefs.setString('pushNotifToken', token);
  } else {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // set value
    await prefs.setString('pushNotifToken', token ?? "00");
  }

  // TODO: Set up background message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  // subscribe to a topic.
  // const topic = 'app_promotion';
  // await messaging.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I think the code above is what is making it take so long but where do I put it instead? How do I make it go faster?

I am running ios 17

Comment: You can try to listen messages after the app has initialised its first UI may be a splash screen